# If $R_R$ is completely reducible then $R$ is a direct sum of finitely many fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show that if $R_R$ is completely reducible then $R$ is a direct sum of finitely many fields, when $R$ is a commutative ring?

I got the reverse direction (which is true). I'm not sure in this direction, how the number of the fields has to be finite.
Thanks,

Comment: Use the Wedderburn-Artin Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As YACP mentions, this follows from an application of Artin-Weddurburn which states:

> A completely reducible ring is a finite direct sum of matrix rings over division rings, that is, if $R$ is completely reducible, then
>   $$R\cong M_{n_1}(\Delta_1)\oplus\ldots\oplus M_{n_m}(\Delta_m)$$
>   for some positive integers $n_i$ and division rings $\Delta_i$.

Now, since $R_R$ is completely reducible, it follows by definition that $R$ is completely reducible.  Next, you should be able to use commutativity to show that all $n_i$ are $1$ and all $\Delta_i$ are fields.